# PowerShell Compare-Object best result

Tags: powershell

I'm looking to compare 2 files containing email addresses that have the following form:

```
$Current = Get-Content -Path myfileref
```

The result is like this:

```
email
user1@mydomain.com
user2@mydomain.com
...
```

```
$target = Get-Content -Path RefFile
```

The result is like this:

```
PrimarySmtpAddress
user1@mydomain.com
user3@mydomain.com
...
```

Note that the header is different for the 2 files

I do :

```
$AddNewMember = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject ($Target.GetEnumerator() -ne "PrimarySmtpAddress") -DifferenceObject ($Current.GetEnumerator() -ne "Mail") |
                Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -contains "==>"}
```

The result is like this:

```
InputObject SideIndicator
"user2@mydomain.com" ==>
...
```

Note the " before and after the email address

Then I would like to use `Add-DistributionGroupMember` command:

```
foreach ($Member in $AddNewMember) {
    Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $ListName -Member $Member.inputObject -DomainController "SpecificDC.myDomain.com" -Confirm:$false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinu
}
```

but nothing happens! Verbose mode tells me

> ...searching object *"user1@mydomain.com" of type "ADrecipient" under the root "$null"* *... ending processing*

I'm pretty certain that the pb comes from the input object, but I go around in circles and can not understand why and solve this problem.

The input object try to pass ""user1@mydomain.com"" and not "user1@mydomain.com".

Comment: You may want to look into [`Import-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/import-csv?view=powershell-3.0).

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Ansgar, you put me on the good way

First: Now, I use **import-csv** instead of **get-content**

Second : I standardized the headers during import-csv (same header, even if it wasn't the same) **Import-Csv -path $File -Header Mail**

then :

**Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $Reflist -DifferenceObject $sql -Property mail | Where-Object {$_.SideIndicator -eq "=>"}**
and the same thing in the other direction, of course. I get usable results

After, easy to make a loop foreach ($member in $UsersToAdd)

**Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $ List -Member $Member.mail -DomainController xxxx -Confirm: $false -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue**
followed by a **Remove-DistributionGroupMember**

thanks again
Olivier